# Script not working outside html body tag

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I have a base template that works fine with the format that I am posting here. However, I want to keep the scripts inside one block, but when I am moving one of the scripts from the body to head, the menu does not drop when clicking. How can I fix this?

**html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        {% block meta_tags %}{% endblock meta_tags%}


    <title>
        {% block title %}BPM App{% endblock title %} 
    </title>

    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'bpmapp/js/topnavbar.js' %}">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/favicon.ico"/>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block javascript %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
            });
        </script>
    {% endblock javascript %}

    {% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% include 'bpmapp/_topnavbar.html' %}

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}

        <script src="static/bpmapp/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js:**

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {
    var b = $("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),
        g = b.children("a"),
        c = $("body"),
        d = -1;

    function f() {
        g.on("click", a);
        b.on("click", function(h) {
            h.stopPropagation()
        })
    }

    function a(j) {
        if (d !== -1) {
            b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")
        }
        var i = $(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),
            h = i.index();
        if (d === h) {
            i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = -1
        } else {
            i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = h;
            c.off("click").on("click", e)
        }
        return false
    }

    function e(h) {
        b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = -1
    }
    return {
        init: f
    }
})();
```

**edited to:**

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu =$( document ).ready(function() {
    var b = $("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),
        g = b.children("a"),
        c = $("body"),
        d = -1;

    $(function f() {
        g.on("click", a);
        b.on("click", function(h) {
            h.stopPropagation()
        })
    });

    $(function a(j) {
        if (d !== -1) {
            b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")
        }
        var i = $(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),
            h = i.index();
        if (d === h) {
            i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = -1
        } else {
            i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = h;
            c.off("click").on("click", e)
        }
        return false
    });

    $(function e(h) {
        b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = -1
    }
    return {
        init: f
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The elements you are trying to augment on the DOM may not be finished loading and therefore do not exists when the javascript runs. By keeping it at the bottom of the body the elements exist when the javascript runs. You can use something like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var cbpHorizontalMenu = {};
});
```

more info here https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I edited the js file, but still I cannot get the menu drop on the click. Is the editing I did is correct at all? You can see the edited js file in the question now

Comment: could you please edit the original js file that I have to see how you change it? I cannot figure out how you want to implement that with the original file

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to include your script in the head of the page (so before the body tag) there will be no escaping the need to include **jQuery** as part of your project (for cross browser reliabilty purposes). I suggest you download it to be able to load it locally from your disk, otherwise, here is the online link for it, you can just add this to your head (just before your own script tag) :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You now need to use **jQuery** to make sure your DOM has completely loaded before your script is executed, you do this by wrapping you whole script code inside the **ready** function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {
        var b = $("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),
            g = b.children("a"),
            c = $("body"),
            d = -1;

        function f() {
            g.on("click", a);
            b.on("click", function(h) {
                h.stopPropagation()
            })
        }

        function a(j) {
            if (d !== -1) {
                b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")
            }
            var i = $(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),
                h = i.index();
            if (d === h) {
                i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
                d = -1
            } else {
                i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
                d = h;
                c.off("click").on("click", e)
            }
            return false
        }

        function e(h) {
            b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = -1
        }
        return {
            init: f
        }
    })();
});
```

Comment: It does not work even before I move the script line to head, so the js code has a problem executing